# Understanding normal distribution graph / data set relation

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

How do I know what is the data set when I have the random variable and what does that help when knowing that it distributes as normal distribution.

Say I have concentration of gas the problem says that it distributes normally . In each day at 8:00 morning . In 2018 .

From the problem :

Is my data set : group of days such that in each day concentration ?

Or : group of hours in each hour concentration ?

How can you tell .

What is the relation with normal distribution graph area

Comment: The data set is distribution of concentration of gas on each day in 2018 at 8.00 A.M.

Comment: so if the area under the normal dist graph is $P(X>t)=0.5 $ does that mean that in $5$% of the days the concentration is higher than $t$ for sure.